# Can't get DataGridView ScrollBars

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am trying to set up datagridview scrollbars, but I can't seem to do it...
The code With what I am doing it:

```
    dgrDataGridView.Height = 320;
    dgrDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.None;
    dgrDataGridView.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
    dgrDataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Is there any mistake or am I missing something in there?

Comment: Maybe they only appear when the gridview has enough data to display to warrant scrolling?

Comment: @Dan there are plenty of data

Comment: Weird because if you create a datagridview in the designer it doesn't set a .ScrollBars property and it definitely has scroll bars when it is full of data to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by myself. Apparently the datagridview was bigger than the windows form, therefore, I wasn't able to see the scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridView` `Scrollbars` are auto visible when data exceeded from data grid visible size both `scrollbar` wil be visible

Comment: if I remove this line "dgrDataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
" the scrollbars do not apear.

Comment: So with that line then you do get the scroll bars?

Comment: With this statement dgrDataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both; scrollbar is visible?